# Custom NSScrollView doesn't scroll NSTableHeaderView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

I have an `NSTableView` embedded within a custom `NSScrollView` subclass, wherein I sometimes do scrolling programmatically, like so:

```
[[self contentView] scrollToPoint:newOffset];
[self reflectScrolledClipView:[self contentView]];
```

When I do this, the `NSTableView` scrolls fine, but its associated `NSTableHeaderView` doesn't move with it. If I use my mouse and scroll the `NSScrollView` normally, however, they move together like they should.

I figure I'm probably just missing a single line somewhere that lets the `NSTableHeaderView` know that it's supposed to scroll too, but I don't know what that is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using `-documentView` instead of `-contentView`?

Comment: @Bavarious I have now. It doesn't work. :P In all honesty, though, using `-documentView` instead of `-contentView` doesn't make a whole lot of sense anyway; `-documentView` returns the `NSTableView` whereas `-contentView` returns the `NSClipView`. In this case, I'm pretty sure I need the `NSClipView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know precisely what kind of black magic goes on under the hood when you scroll an `NSScrollView` containing an `NSTableHeaderView` with the mouse, but it looks like it handles it internally somewhere. To circumvent this, I now *only* scroll the `NSTableView` programatically (by overriding the functions that would handle user input), and then I scroll the `NSTableHeaderView` myself, like so:

```
NSTableHeader *header = [[self documentView] headerView];
[header setBoundsOrigin:NSMakePoint(newOffset.x,[header bounds].origin.y)];
```

Comment: The black magic is that the NSScrollView inspects the document view for a "headerView" method/property, and if found, treats it this way. It's not documented anywhere I can find, except this mailing list: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Jun/msg01464.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on a cell-based NSTableView with Swift 5 / MacOS 14.

The NSScrollView enclosing an NSTableView owns both the contentView and the headerView of the NSTableView (and the cornerView, which I do not use), and is normally responsible of coordinating their scrolling.

- When scrolling with mouse, the NSScrollView  internal magic handle correctly the scrolling of the header view.
- When scrolling programmatically the NSClipView using scroll(to:) + reflectScrolledClipView, NSScrollView fails to scroll of the headerView.

I use this protocol in order to scroll programmatically the headerView too, which allows me to scroll programmatically using this protocol:

```
extension NSTableView : ScrollingProtocol {

    func getScrollView() -> NSScrollView? {
        return enclosingScrollView
    }

    func getVisibleOrigin() -> NSPoint? {
        return enclosingScrollView?.documentVisibleRect.origin
    }

    func scrollToOrigin(_ targetOrigin: NSPoint) {
        guard let currentOrigin = getVisibleOrigin(),
            let scrollView = enclosingScrollView
            else { return }

        if (!NSEqualPoints(targetOrigin, currentOrigin)) {
            let clipView = scrollView.contentView
            clipView.scroll(to: targetOrigin)

            // Workaround because NSClipView.scroll(to:) does not scroll
            // the headerView of NSTableView
            if let headerView = headerView {
                let x = targetOrigin.x
                let y = headerView.bounds.origin.y
                if let headerClipView = headerView.superview as? NSClipView {
                    headerClipView.scroll(to: NSMakePoint(x, y))
                }
            }
            scrollView.reflectScrolledClipView(clipView)
        }
    }
}
```